# JSONObject to JSONArray FAULT in .getJSONArray("message");

Tags: android, json

I am trying to convert an JSONObject to JSONArray. I found a lot of examples and tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

So now I've tried to send an JSON encoded array via POST to an PHP script.  However, it generates a fault if I try to convert the JSONObject to an JSONArray. The cast looks like :

```
JSONArray jsonArr = jsonParent.getJSONArray("message");
```

The LogCat outputs:

> 08-17 19:00:32.324: E/SmsReceiver(17846): Exception
>   smsReceiverorg.json.JSONException: No value for message

Here's all the code to give you context about what I want to do:

```
// Generating the Objects
JSONObject jsonChild= new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonParent= new JSONObject();

try {       

    jsonChild.put("with_img", false);
    jsonChild.put("message", message);
    jsonChild.put("img", ""); // base64 codiertes Bild
    jsonChild.put("number", senderNum);
    jsonChild.put("time", time); // UNIX Timestamp

} catch (JSONException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}

// here enter code here expire the problem
JSONArray jsonArr  = jsonParent.getJSONArray("message");

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/ticker.php");

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonArr.toString());
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
httppost.setEntity(se);

HttpEntity entitySend = httppost.getEntity();
String htmlSend = EntityUtils.toString(entitySend);

Log.d("Sended:", ""+ htmlSend);

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    // Just for reading the server response.
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String htmlResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    Log.d("Received:", ""+ htmlResponse);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, what you want to do is this:

```
// Generating one Object
JSONObject jsonThingy = new JSONObject();

try {       

    jsonThingy.put("with_img", false);
    jsonThingy.put("message", message);
    jsonThingy.put("img", ""); // base64 codiertes Bild
    jsonThingy.put("number", senderNum);
    jsonThingy.put("time", time); // UNIX Timestamp


} catch (JSONException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonThingy.toString());

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/ticker.php");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", se));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsonParent` object simply doesn't contain a value with the name `message`. If you want more help, paste the content of your json data.

Answer (score 0):

> So now I've tried to send an JSON encoded array via POST to an PHP script. However, it generates a fault if I try to convert the JSONObject to an JSONArray. The cast looks like :
>
> > JSONArray jsonArr = jsonParent.getJSONArray("message");

You aren't casting your `JSONObject` to a `JSONArray` in that line. You are trying to get an array which is inside `jsonParent` named "message". Basically, if your JSONObject contains:

```
{
    ...
    "message" : [
        {
           "attr1" : "value1",
           "attr2" : "value2",
           ...
        },
        {
           ...
        }
        ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

them `jsonArr` will return that message array for you.

If you want to add your `JSONObject` to a `JSONArray`, them create a `JSONArray` and add that to it.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsonChild);
```